# What is the difference between pseudo classical inheritance and prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've read that there are 3 inheritance patterns in JavaScript:

- Pseudo-classical
- Functional
- Prototypal

I understand how functional inheritance is different from the other two by not using the prototype chain that JavaScript provides.

But I really don't see the difference between the other two. The basic idea is that objects inherit from `prototype` objects and this leads to a prototype chain of inheritence. But is there a real difference between psuedo-classical and prototypal?

Comment: there are many inheritance patterns. using prototypal to reproduce classical language's OOP is called psudeo-classical. That doesn't include other aspects of prototypal inheritance like global object methods, fn.apply, etc.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633762/classical-inheritance-vs-protoypal-inheritance-in-javascript) question and it answers.