# Class compared to Prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand what actually happens when you create a new instance of a class with ES6. As far as I can tell, a new instance is created with properties as defined in the constructor and then the rest of the methods in the class are actually properties on the prototype object

For example

```
class Dog {
    constructor(name){
      this.name = name
    }

    speak (){
        console.log('Woof')
    }
}
```

Would be the equivelant to

```
function Dog(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log('Woof');
}
```

In the class example. If I create an instance of my Dog class, Is the prototype of that method pointing to the Dog class itself or is it a completely new object? Because when I `Object.getPrototypeOf(myDog)` it returns `Dog {}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [classical inheritance vs prototypal inheritance in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633762/classical-inheritance-vs-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript)

Comment: The JS class syntax is just syntax sugar for the prototypes. In both cases `.getPrototypeOf()` will point to the object `Dog.prototype`. Internally the class syntax will be 'rewrittten' to the prototype syntax. The way it's shown in the debugger will depend on which browser / debugger.

Comment: I see, So this is acting pretty much the same. So when I set a speak method in the class Dog, is that actually setting a method named speak on Dog.prototype?

Comment: yes, all the methods you define with the class syntax become functions inside the prototype object.

Comment: Thanks Shilly, this makes it a lot clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are functionally exactly the same. Here are some interesting properties about prototypes and classes to point out though:

```js
class Dog1 {
    constructor(name){
      this.name = name
    }

    speak (){                    // adds speak method to the prototype of Dog1
        console.log('Woof')
    }
}

Dog1.prototype.speak = () => {    // overwrites speak method to the prototype of Dog1
 console.log('Different Woof');
}

console.log(typeof Dog1); // Class keyword is just syntactic sugar for constructor function

const newDog = new Dog1('barkie');

newDog.speak();

/////////////////////////////

function Dog2(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Dog2.prototype.speak =  () => {
    console.log('Woof');
}

const aDog = new Dog2('fluffy');

aDog.__proto__.speak();  // the __proto__ property references the prototype
aDog.speak();  // the __proto__ property is not necessary, it will automatically climb the protochain if the property is not found on the object itself.
```

I left some comments in order to point out the quirks which can be a bit hard to grasp. I you have any further questions about it you can leave a comment. Hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: Would be nice to also mention that `__proto__` is deprecated if you teach people the existance of `__proto__`. :)

Comment: …or even better, don't teach them about `__proto__` at all and just use `Object.getPrototypOf`!

Comment: Thankyou, this is very helpful and makes perfect sense.