# How to assign multiple values to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

Say that I have an object with key/value pair as the following:

```
var someVar = {
    color: "white",
    font_size: "30px",
    font_weight: "normal"
...some more variables and functions
};
```

Is there a way to do a multiple assignment to those keys instead of having to do something like this:

```
someVar.color = "blue";
someVar.font_size = "30px";
...
```

Comment: jQuery.extend, or for .. in loop through an object with your desired properties and set them on some object. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776683/1008798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through another object:

```
var thingsToAdd = {
    color: "blue",
    font_size: "30px"
};
for (var x in thingsToAdd) someVar[x] = thingsToAdd[x];
```

Or, you could use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) (***WARNING***: this is ALMOST CERTAINLY a **bad** idea! See the link. I am only posting this for educational purposes; you should almost *never* use `with` in production code!):

```
with (someVar) {
    color = "blue";
    font_size = "30px";
}
```

Comment: Worked! @Dalius mentioned first something similar, but I will give it to you since you mentioned about "with".

Answer (score 13):

With ES2015 you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const someVar = {
    color: "white",
    font_size: "30px",
    font_weight: "normal"
};

const newVar = Object.assign({}, someVar, { 
    color: "blue", 
    font_size: "30px"});

console.log(newVar);
```

=>

```
{
    color: "blue",
    font_size: "30px",
    font_weight: "normal"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

With ES6 Spread Operator:

```
someVar = {...someVar, color: "blue", font_size: "30px"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Object Constructors.
Would look something like this:

```
function someVar (color,fontSize, fontWeight){
    this.color = color,
    this.fontSize = fontSize,
    this.fontWeight = fontWeight
};
var var1 = new someVar("red","12px","45px");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var myvar ={};
myvar['color']='red';
myvar['width'] ='100px';
alert(myvar.color);
```

or `alert(myvar['color']);`

Comment: OP specifically requested a better approach than setting each property individually.

Comment: This is the dynamic assignment with respect to key, as like if key is any variable as `var col = 'color'; myvar[col] = 'red';`