# Assign to multiple values in object using destructure-like syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a cleaner way of setting the values `a`,`b`, and `c` in `bar`.  Something similar to ES6 destructuring-assignment syntax?

```
bar = { foo: 10, a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, baz: 14 };

myFunc = (myObj) => {
    const { foo } = myObj;
    let a, b, c;
    a = 1 + foo;
    b = 2 + foo;
    c = 3 + foo;
    myObj.a = a;
    myObj.b = b;
    myObj.c = c;
}

myFunc(bar);
```

Assuming that `bar` has already been instantiated somewhere else, I'd like to set the new values without creating/assigning a new object to `bar`.  We could do something like this `myObj = {...myObj, a, b, c}`, but that'd assign a new object to `bar`, from my understanding.

Comment: Given they are constants, how about `const bar = {foo: 10, a: 11, b: 12, c: 13};`? However, I think what you really are looking for are [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [How to assign multiple values to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109929/how-to-assign-multiple-values-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774057/8535397), you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
bar = { foo: 10, a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, baz: 14 };

myFunc = (myObj) => {
    const { foo } = myObj;
    let a, b, c;
    a = 1 + foo;
    b = 2 + foo;
    c = 3 + foo;
    Object.assign(myObj, {a: a, b: b, c: c});
}

myFunc(bar);
```

or of course

```
    const { foo } = myObj;
    Object.assign(myObj, {a: 1 + foo, b: 2 + foo, c: 3 + foo})
```

Comment: `Object.assign(myObj, {a, b, c});` inside of `myFunc` did it for me!  Wish it was prettier though.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 did not bring in any features that would make this code simpler. There is one feature available, but it is a best practice not to use it. The [with keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

```
with (bar) {
 a = foo+1
 b = foo+2
 c = foo+3
}
```

The best way to make that code shorter would be to wrap the logic into a method call if it is being re-used a lot.

Comment: In every new ES6 syntax (like `class` or modules), `with` is strictly prohibited. For good reason.

Comment: Thanks, Leland.  I'd like to avoid usage of `with` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object literal shorthand and construct your object the other way round:

```
const foo = 10;
const a = 1+foo, b = 2+foo, c = 3+foo;
const bar = { foo, a, b, c };
```

which of course could be shortened to simply

```
const bar = { foo, a: 1+foo, b: 2+foo, c: 3+foo };
```

Comment: See my edit please.  Let's assume `bar` has been created elsewhere.  I'd like to streamline the assignments to `a`, `b`, and `c` in `bar` without creating a new object.

Comment: Well you could do `Object.assign(bar, {a,b,c})`, but I think it's even simpler to just avoid those local variables and write `bar.a = 1+foo; bar.b = 2+foo; bar.c = 3+foo;`. I don't see what would be wrong with that (of course your example is a bit repetitive, I guess you'd need to show us your actual use case).