# Good way to write extend method of a contructor? (please see my attempt)

Tags: javascript

I've been following along a blog post on [JavaScript inheritance](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/js-inheritance-by-example.html). I wanted to slightly adapt this and try to write something more like I've seen in Backbone (extend method). See I set about it, and run into problems. Then I came across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430279/javascript-object-extending). It was so much simpler. So after some minor tweaks to that I set about writing a way each extended constructor could have their own extend method (inherited from Base). This is what I have:

```
var Base = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Base.prototype.extend = function(new_constructor){
    //new_constructor.prototype = new this.constructor();
    new_constructor.prototype = Object.create(this.constructor.prototype);
    new_constructor.prototype.constructor = new_constructor;

    return new_constructor;
}

var Robot = Base.prototype.extend(function(name, material){
    Base.call(this, name)
    this.material = material
    this.type = 'robot';
});

var T1000 = Robot.prototype.extend(function(options){
    Robot.call(this, options.name, options.material)
    this.guns = options.guns;
    this.type = 'killer robot';
});

robot = new Robot("Boutros", "metal");
t1000 = new T1000({name: "Arnie", material:"flesh/metal", guns:3});

console.log(robot)
console.log(t1000)
```

Anyway seems to work, but I'm a little new to this. Can anyone suggest any limitations with this approach. I'd like to use something like this when I create objects in JavaScript but don't want to run into any issues later on. Would appreciate your feedback.

Btw, here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bizt/Y9bL9/1/)

Comment: this may fit better down at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `extend` function does everything to do prototypical inheritance correctly.

However, it doesn't make much sense to place it on the prototype of `Base`. Why should `robot` or `t1000` inherit this method? It doesn't do what you would expect from it (`t2000 = t1000.extend(…)`?).

You'd better make it a static method:

```
function extend(parent_constructor, new_constructor) {
    new_constructor.prototype = Object.create(parent_constructor.prototype);
    new_constructor.prototype.constructor = new_constructor;
    return new_constructor;
}

var Base = function(name){
    …
};
var Robot = extend(Base, function(name, material){
    …
});
var T1000 = extend(Robot, function(options){
    …
});
```

Or you make it a method of all constructor functions, by placing it on the native `Function.prototype`:

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(new_constructor) {
    new_constructor.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    new_constructor.prototype.constructor = new_constructor;
    return new_constructor;
}

var Base = function(name){
    …
};
var Robot = Base.extend(function(name, material){
    …
});
var T1000 = Robot.extend(function(options){
    …
});
```