# Write a function "extends" which simplifies the JS based inheritance

Tags: javascript

how might we can write in Java script as I'm new in the world of Java script.

```
 function Car() {
     this.type = "Car";
   };

function Ferrari() {
     this.name = "Ferrari";
   };

Ferrari.extends(Car);
   var f = new Ferrari();
   f.name // Ferrari
   f.type // Car
```

None of the answer help me as i'm following [eloquentjavascript book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10430875/921204 - Also make sure to read the comments.

Comment: While the duplicate isn't an exact match for the question, the accepted answer covers it (and lots of other stuff besides). There are also many other resources on the internet for how to extend javascript "classes". Once you've done some research on those and come up with a preferred solution, feel free to ask questions about that too. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascipt is a hybrid language with [prototypical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) approach. To "extend" in js context is to inherit by the prototype. Some modern browser supports Object.create() which internally iterates through each prototype property and copy across.

This snippet is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
Examples
Example: Classical inheritance with Object.create()

Below is an example of how to use Object.create() to achieve classical inheritance. This is for single inheritance, which is all that JavaScript supports.

// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle? ' + (rect instanceof Rectangle)); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape? ' + (rect instanceof Shape)); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so how we can write own extend methods

Comment: yes, but via the object's prototype. example above "subclass extends superclass". but do check out the link that the moderator has provided to a  similar topic with answers. good luck and have fun prototyping!