# Can't Call Prototype Function from Callback

Tags: javascript, prototype

Per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281845/1477388) I understand I can create a javascript object with it's own properties and methods like so.

However, when attempting to assign a particular method via a callback, it doesn't work!

Why can't I simply pass the method instead of passing the entire object?

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lson3qwx/1/

```
// base `Person` prototype
var Person = {
   name : '',
   age  : 22,
   type : 'human',
   msg: function(message) {
    alert(message);
   },
   greet: function() {
       //console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name + ' and I am a ' + this.type + '.' );
       this.msg('Hi, my name is ' + this.name + ' and I am a ' + this.type + '.');
   }
};

// create an instance of `Person`:
var skywalker = Object.create(Person);
skywalker.name = 'Anakin Skywalker';
//skywalker.greet(); // 'Hi, my name is Anakin Skywalker and I am a human.'

var callbackTest1 = function(callback) {
    callback.greet();
}

var callbackTest2 = function(callback) {
    callback();
}

callbackTest1(skywalker); // this works
callbackTest2(skywalker.greet); // this doesn't
```

Comment: `Why can't I simply pass the method instead of passing the entire object?` because of how `this` works in JS. `callback()` in `callbackTest2` is equivalent to `skywalker.greet.call(null)`.

Comment: The difference is the scope. In the second case, when you execute `greet`, `this` is not Skywalker. But you can do: `callbackTest2(skywalker.greet.bind(skywalker));`

Comment: Incidentally, fighting the use of `new` is basically an anti-pattern, since newer core constructor functions and ES6 classes all require the use of `new`.

Comment: You can do : `callbackTest2(skywalker.greet());`.

Comment: @MrGeek No, in this case, `callbackTest2` is basically useless because you `greet` before even executing `callbackTest2`, and you're passing the result of `greet` (null) as a parameter.

Comment: @MrGeek, this does something completely different

Comment: @blex Wow, thanks that does work.  It's a bit unclear what it is doing.  I understand it is binding "skywalker" as the context.  Is there a better way to write this?  I am simply trying to pass a method property of an object as a callback.

Comment: I'm not really good at this, but here is a way I can think of: https://jsfiddle.net/f0L32prd/

Comment: @blex Awesome, that's so much cleaner.  Well done!