# Is there a standard way for Javascript classes to refer to each other?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, hoisting

I was wondering, is there a standard way for class properties and methods to refer to each other in their declaration? For example:

```
class A {
  methodA(){
    b.methodB()
    ...
  }
}

class B {
  methodB(){...}
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B(); 

///will throw ReferenceError: Cannot access 'b' before initialization;
```

I understand that you can add methodA in later after all class/object declarations, but it gets quite untidy after many repetitions, which I feel like defeats the purpose of classes. Or that you can delay the reference through some other means. Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Javascript has no "classes". The `class` keyword is just there to make it look familiar. It should have been `proto` instead of `class`.

It's better to use `mixins`. Also it very much depends on whether to be able to propagate changes to methodB to all decedents of A, or if you want that.

See also ["prose-like syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430279/extending-an-object-in-javascript/28281845#28281845)

#### No propagation - copying

If you don't need propagation and you need to copy a lot of methods over:

```
const A = {
    name: 'I am A.'
}

const B = {
    name: 'I am B.', // this will overwrite A when we #assign. so be careful to assign it back
    methodB() {
        console.log(`${this.name} - foo`)
    }
}

const a = Object.create(A)

Object.assign(a, B)
a.name = A.name

// methodB is changed but it won't propagate.
B.methodB = function() {
    console.log(`${this.name} - bar`)
}

a.methodB() // I am A. - foo
B.methodB() // I am B. - bar
```

#### With propagation.

And if you only need 1 or a few methods:

```
const A = {
    name: 'I am A.'
}

const B = {
    name: 'I am B.',
    methodB() {
        console.log(`${this.name} - foo`)
    }
}

const a = Object.create(A)

a.methodA = function() {
    B.methodB.call(this)
}

B.methodB = function() {
    console.log(`${this.name} - bar`)
}

a.methodA() // I am A. - bar
B.methodB() // I am B. - bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always keep instantiating the other `classes` in your class, say `A` and access their methods and properties like this.

```js
class A {
  methodA(){
    const b = new B(); 
    b.methodB()
  }
}

class B {
  methodB(){console.log("Here I am")}
}

const a = new A();
a.methodA();
```

Or, You can use `inheritance`.

```
class A {}
class B extends A{
 constructor() { super(); //}
}
```